# MySQL tab completion on OS X

Tags: macos, mysql

I've got tab completion working for tables and columns (--auto-rehash), is there any way to also have tab completion for SQL commands eg

```
SE (tab) --> SELECT
SELECT * FR (tab) --> SELECT * FROM
```

Comment: stackoverflow question?

Comment: I'm not sure what your interface is. Is this some kind of MySQL client software, or the command line perhaps?

Comment: Looks like the stock `mysql` client program to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably talking about mysql command-line client.

For a single session, you can enable tab completion with command line switch *--auto-rehash* .

To set this behavior default, check your mysql configuration file my.cnf, find [mysql] region, and replace line

```
no-auto-rehash
```

with

```
auto-rehash
```

Comment: ahh, SQL commands must be typed in caps for autocompletion to work

Comment: Not working for me. Something to do with vi key binding?

Comment: @FrozenFlame: I found the solution to this problem (which was what I was looking for when I found this answer) on Stack Overflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216471/how-to-get-vi-keybindings-to-work-in-mysql-client/24206216#24206216